# Finding the ranges of values in two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have two arrays A and B which are both (always) the same length. For example:

*A = array([  0,  26,  48,  70,  94, 119])
B = array([  1,  30,  50,  71,  94, 123])*

I'm struggling to find a way in which I could get the range between the pairs in one list. The outcome should look something like this:

*C = array([0,1,26,27,28,29,30,48,49,50,70,71,94,119,120,121,122,123])*

I tried doing:

```
for i in A:
   for k in B:
      print(range(i,k))
```

which results in a mess of ranges.

Any helpers out there?

Comment: You can do `n_ranges(A, B+1)` using the answer in the dupe

Answer (score 0):

From notation, I guess your arrays are `np.array`, so you can do:

```
C = np.concatenate([np.arange(a,b) for a,b in zip(A,B+1)])
```

Output:

```
array([  0,   1,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  48,  49,  50,  70,  71,  94,
       119, 120, 121, 122, 123])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just be able to find the range by selecting the first value of the first array [0] and the last value of the second array [-1]:

```
 print(range(A[0],B[-1])
```